# How does Reserved keyword * works in sql

Tags: sql, db2

How does rdbms tools execute * in select statements. reason of asking the question is its different usage in different rdbms tools.
Ex: oracle and db2 gives error in below statements, however works fine in mysql,mssql,sybase. Looks like an issue with sql parser.

```
select col_name,* from table_name
```

Or

```
select *,col_name from table_name
```

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL say that a single `*` in the select list may not be combined with anything else. I.e. Oracle and DB2 are standard compliant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However mssql from microsoft and sybase from sap also runs on the same ANSI standard. And they allow the above queries to run perfectly. So is this anything related to oracle and DB2 parser not allowing the above sql's to run properly..

Comment: Most dbms products are more or less ANSI SQL compliant (some more, and some less.) And most of them have their own "extensions", like here.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle (and probably DB2 as well) accepts an unadorned `*` *only when there are no other column references or expressions in the `SELECT`*.

However, it is always allowed with a table alias.  So you can write:

```
select col_name, t.*
from table_name t
```

Just one caution:  the result set will have two columns with the same name, which can cause other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon.However is there a proper justfication as to why only oracle and DB2 doesnt allow this to happen as mssql and sybase does allow them to execute and give results. Does it have anything to do with the sql grammer of oracle and db2 parsers not allowing this to happen.

Comment: @chetansir . . . Perhaps it has to do with the fact that Oracle and IBM were pretty much the only databases when the standards were first created.  `SELECT *` was intended as shorthand for "all columns", so perhaps it was viewed as a single syntactic element, rather than `*` standing for "all columns".

Answer (score 0):

Db2 11.1 supports unqualified `*`s. E.g.

```
db2 "create table table_name( col_name int )"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "select col_name,* from table_name"

COL_NAME    COL_NAME   
----------- -----------

  0 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization

> SQL implementations are incompatible between vendors and do not necessarily completely follow standards.

See the Wikipedia link above for some of the "several reasons for this lack of portability between database systems"